# How to find the cgi-bin in the workspace for cloud 9?

Tags: html, cgi, cloud9-ide, bin

How can I find the cgi-bin for cloud 9, I need it for a contact form page?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://docs.c9.io/running_python_cgi.html for a tutorial on how to use CGI using python. Most steps should be similar no matter which language you choose to write your CGI scripts in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The link seems to be broken.